# Getting zones from raster?

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, polygonize

[image]

I'm wondering if it is possible to get zones based on a raster file as you can see in my attached image (hand-made).

Is there a tool or an idea to get a result like that?

Comment: Looks like you want **classification** followed by **rasterization**. Any GIS software can do that. Try QGIS.

Comment: Points for the handmade drawing :). As mentioned above, the simplest way is to reclassify your raster into categories of your liking. R.reclass in the grass tools is good for that. Then you want to polygonise (not rasterise as j08lue probably wrote by accident) your relcassed raster. Again the grass tools can do that or there is the qgis tool under raster conversion  (I think it's there...).

Comment: Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are working on a single band raster (such as DEM), and need to outline cell boundaries at certain threshold value(s).

This reminds me of **Whitebox-GAT** `Contour` tool, whose lines *(below; B)* follow cell boundaries.

[image]

In the meantime, `Contour` operation is usually followed by `Smooth` in the Whitebox-GAT as below.

[image]